# setup.py specify link to use for install_requires

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am running python3 and trying to require an install of oauth2. The problem is that the std pypi repository doesn't have py3 support for oauth2. Therefore, I need to use [this version](https://github.com/tseaver/python-oauth2/tree/py3)

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        ...
        oauth2,
        ... ]
    dependency_links=['https://github.com/tseaver/python-oauth2/archive/py3.zip']
    ...
)
```

The full setup.py file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cloudformdesign/4791c46fe7cd52eb61cd/edit)

This doesn't work -- `python setup.py install` still tries to install the py2 version of oauth2. Looking at [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html), **dependency_links** says "These links will be used if needed" -- I'm guessing it thinks it doesn't need them.

I have tried one obvious solution, and that is to get the version number of a working version. and say oauth2==1.5.211 -- this doesn't work either (I guess both the 2 and 3 branches have the same version? Aug)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: if this dosent support python 3x , why you installing it

Comment: the branch in git has python 3x support. The standard pypi one doesn't